# Order type of infinite products?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two totally ordered sets with order types $\alpha$ and $\beta$, respectively ($\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals). The set of functions $X\to Y$ is given by the product...

$$Y^X=\prod_{x\in X}Y$$

What is the order type of $Y^X$? Is it the same as the order type of $\displaystyle \beta^\alpha=\prod_{i\in\alpha}\beta$?

---

Specifically,  how does the order type of this infinite product differ from how we define the product order for smaller sets. As an example, consider the set of sequences of natural numbers...

$$\Bbb{N}^\Bbb{N}=\prod_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\Bbb{N}$$

For each finite subset $[n]=\{m\in\Bbb{N}\mid m\le n\}$, we have that the order type of the product...

$$otp(\Bbb{N}^{[n]})=otp(\prod_{i\in[n]}\Bbb{N})=otp(\Bbb{N})^n$$

...is the same as the product of the order type (namely $\omega\cdot\omega\cdots\omega=\omega^n$), given the product order. Clearly the order type of $\Bbb{N}^\Bbb{N}$ cannot be regarded as the limit of the sequence $\omega^2,\omega^3,\cdots$, because this would suggest that the set of all infinite sequences of natural numbers is countable, which it is not.

Comment: It's your choice. The most natural thing to choose would be the lexicographic order.

Comment: @RobArthan I assumed that the order could be defined in terms of the product order by considering the union of the products indexed by the finite subsets of $X$ - but apparently this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is to look at the least point of difference (**lexicographic order**): given $f,g:\alpha\rightarrow\beta$ with $f\not=g$, there is some smallest $\gamma\in\alpha$ with $f(\gamma)\not=g(\gamma)$ - call this "$\mu_{f,g}$." Then we set $$f\triangleleft g\iff f(\mu_{f,g})<g(\mu_{f,g}),$$ where "$<$" refers to the usual ordering on $\beta$.

Note that the existence of such a $\gamma$ (and hence the definition of $\triangleright$) relies on the assumption that $\alpha$ is well-ordered. In general, there's no "explicit" way to put a linear ordering on the set of maps between linear orders in general (even if the target is assumed to be well-ordered): it is consistent with ZF that the powerset of $\mathbb{R}$ is not linearly orderable.

Also, note that this is quite different from ordinal exponentiation. Remember, in ordinal exponentiation we have $2^\omega=\omega$ - the point being that ordinal exponentiation is defined so that $$\alpha^\beta=\sup\{\alpha^\gamma: \gamma<\beta\}.$$ *(It's only half-continuous, by the way - it's not true that $\alpha^\beta=\sup\{\gamma^\beta:\gamma<\alpha\}$, and you can see that by considering $\alpha=\omega,\beta=2$.)*

Comment: If $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{R})$ is treated as a poset (ordered by inclusion), would the union of a set of disjoint chains (ordered by inclusion) be a linear order on $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{R})$?

Comment: @R.Burton How are you comparing elements in different chains? If I have a set $C_i$ ($i\in I$) of disjoint chains in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ *where $I$ is already linearly ordered* I can get a linear order on the union $\bigsqcup_{i\in I}C_i$ (to compare elements from different chains, compare their chains' indices). But if I don't have an ordering on the index set there's no good way to combine the chains into a linear order. E.g. take $I=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ and $C_i=i$; then $\{C_i:i\in I\}$ is a partition of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ into disjoint chains but this doesn't help at all.

Comment: There's nothing to say that such a task can be accomplished - indeed the set of such chains must contain undefinable members - only that it is "possible" to create such a set and to order it, much in the same sense that it is "possible" to realize the totality of the continuum of real numbers.

Comment: I'm also not sure what the cardinality of the set of *disjoint* chains is. It's certainly at least $\mathfrak{c}$, but it could be $2^\mathfrak{c}$. If it *is* $\mathfrak{c}$ then I suppose you could use $I=\Bbb{R}$ with the usual order, otherwise, it's just a "this exists" kind of thing. I would think that, if nothing else, $I=\omega_2$ should suffice.

Comment: @R.Burton I don't really understand your first comment. Certainly nothing along these lines is going to get around the fact that the statement is simply not provable in ZF alone (and I think you're missing the point of my comment above, that ordering a set of disjoint chains is generally no easier than just ordering all of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ at once).

Comment: Your second comment also doesn't really make sense to me - what do you mean "**the** set of disjoint chains"? There are different sets of disjoint chains out there. I suppose you're asking about the *smallest number of disjoint chains needed to cover $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$? This is consistently much larger than $\omega_2$ since it's consistent with ZFC that $\omega_2<\mathfrak{c}$. Regardless, this seems to be going a bit far from your original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96631/discussion-between-r-burton-and-noah-schweber).